# Child element with height 100% is including parent's padding

Tags: html, css

I have a relatively simple setup inside part of my website:

```
<body>
<!-- ... a few <div> ... -->
    <div class="root"><div><a><span></span></a></div></div>
<!-- ... a few </div> ... -->
</body>
```

- The `body` is `white-space: nowrap` and `font-size: 0px`.
- The outer `div.root` is `display: grid` with an explicit, static `width` and `height`. Single row/column of `min-content`.
- The inner `div` is `display: block` with no explicit `height`.
- The `a` is `display: inline-block`. It has padding but no explicit `height`. `line-height` and `font-size` are explicitly 0.
- The `span` is `display: inline-block` with `height: 100%`. It is completely empty.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3h8cdkov/1/)

In the JSFiddle example the `span` (which would be pictured as a red rectangle below) is 0 height regardless of the `a`'s padding. This is what I would expect.

[image: x]

But on my website the `span`'s height is controlled by the `a`'s padding! If the `a`'s padding is 100px then the `span`'s height is 100px. If the `a`'s padding is 0 then the `span`'s height is 0. If I explicitly set the `a`'s height to any value (including `fit-content`) other than `auto` the behavior goes away and the `span`'s height ignores the padding of `a` (as in the JSFiddle example). Also, the `div` doesn't seem to be accounting for the height of the `span`/`a`.

[image: x] [image: x] [image: x] [image: x]

Neither `border-box` or `content-box` settings for `box-sizing` (applied to all elements) make a difference (in both the JSFiddle and my website). The only notable difference between the example and my website is that on my website the above setup is contained within other elements. I've checked the whole ancestor chain for anything that might lead to this behavior, but I can't find anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions to try to find the culprit? Can anyone reproduce the behavior I'm seeing on my website?

Browser: `Microsoft Edge 103.0.1264.62`

| Element | JSFiddle | My Website |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `div.root` | [image: x] | [image: x] |
| `div` | [image: x] | [image: x] Why is this height 30px when the `a` is height 60px? |
| `a` | [image: x] | [image: x] |
| `span` | [image: x] | [image: x] |

Comment: did you declare the <doctype> and the beginning of your HTML file?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Dammit!! Quirks Mode strikes again! There was some HTML before the <!DOCTYPE html> that shouldn't have been there. Removing it eliminated the weird behavior. Thank you, please write an answer and I'll credit you